# iCloud Calendar hide my Apple ID email?

Tags: icloud, calendar

I have a custom domain (hosted on Apple Mail) as my email to my Apple ID. I would like not to use/share that email and have it exclusively for my Apple ID (keep it private as much as possible). My Apple ID has an alias as well (the @icloud.com auto-generated by Apple).

When I create a calendar invitation (from my iCloud account), the email/invitation is sent using the email associated with my Apple ID. I wondered if there is a way to use the alias email instead?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. But why do you want to do that? What is the advantage of having an email address exclusively for your Apple ID if it goes to the same mailbox as your @icloud.com address?

Comment: It means that people who know your public email won't be able to target you. They would need to know your email address + password + 2FA which makes it far more difficult to find out.